# PHPExcel setCellValue corrupts data if called in for cycle

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to generate an Excel spreadsheet from PHP using PHPExcel and I've run into a weird behaviour. My data come from a mysql database, once I've collected everything I need and stored all information into an array of objects, I try to create my Excel by calling setCellValue in a cycle, this is my code:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($art);$i++) {     
    $r=$i+2;
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A'.$r, ''.utf8_encode($art[$i]->field1))
        ->setCellValue('B'.$r, ''.utf8_encode($art[$i]->field2))
        ->setCellValue('C'.$r, ''.utf8_encode($art[$i]->field3))
        ->setCellValue('D'.$r, ''.utf8_encode($art[$i]->field4))
        ->setCellValue('E'.$r, ''.utf8_encode($art[$i]->field5))
        ->setCellValue('F'.$r, ''.utf8_encode($art[$i]->field6));
}
```

The output result in an unreadable spreadsheet filled of random chars, not even the coordinates are respected. The most strange thing is that if i call this method six times instead of using a for cycle, it works perfectly. This code gives a perfect output:

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A2', ''.utf8_encode($art[0]->field1))
        ->setCellValue('B2', ''.utf8_encode($art[0]->field2))
        ->setCellValue('C2', ''.utf8_encode($art[0]->field3))
        ->setCellValue('D2', ''.utf8_encode($art[0]->field4))
        ->setCellValue('E2', ''.utf8_encode($art[0]->field5))
        ->setCellValue('F2', ''.utf8_encode($art[0]->field6));

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A3', ''.utf8_encode($art[1]->field1))
        ->setCellValue('B3', ''.utf8_encode($art[1]->field2))
        ->setCellValue('C3', ''.utf8_encode($art[1]->field3))
        ->setCellValue('D3', ''.utf8_encode($art[1]->field4))
        ->setCellValue('E3', ''.utf8_encode($art[1]->field5))
        ->setCellValue('F3', ''.utf8_encode($art[1]->field6));

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A4', ''.utf8_encode($art[2]->field1))
        ->setCellValue('B4', ''.utf8_encode($art[2]->field2))
        ->setCellValue('C4', ''.utf8_encode($art[2]->field3))
        ->setCellValue('D4', ''.utf8_encode($art[2]->field4))
        ->setCellValue('E4', ''.utf8_encode($art[2]->field5))
        ->setCellValue('F4', ''.utf8_encode($art[2]->field6));

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A5', ''.utf8_encode($art[3]->field1))
        ->setCellValue('B5', ''.utf8_encode($art[3]->field2))
        ->setCellValue('C5', ''.utf8_encode($art[3]->field3))
        ->setCellValue('D5', ''.utf8_encode($art[3]->field4))
        ->setCellValue('E5', ''.utf8_encode($art[3]->field5))
        ->setCellValue('F5', ''.utf8_encode($art[3]->field6));

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A6', ''.utf8_encode($art[4]->field1))
        ->setCellValue('B6', ''.utf8_encode($art[4]->field2))
        ->setCellValue('C6', ''.utf8_encode($art[4]->field3))
        ->setCellValue('D6', ''.utf8_encode($art[4]->field4))
        ->setCellValue('E6', ''.utf8_encode($art[4]->field5))
        ->setCellValue('F6', ''.utf8_encode($art[4]->field6));

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A7', ''.utf8_encode($art[5]->field1))
        ->setCellValue('B7', ''.utf8_encode($art[5]->field2))
        ->setCellValue('C7', ''.utf8_encode($art[5]->field3))
        ->setCellValue('D7', ''.utf8_encode($art[5]->field4))
        ->setCellValue('E7', ''.utf8_encode($art[5]->field5))
        ->setCellValue('F7', ''.utf8_encode($art[5]->field6));

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A8', ''.utf8_encode($art[6]->field1))
        ->setCellValue('B8', ''.utf8_encode($art[6]->field2))
        ->setCellValue('C8', ''.utf8_encode($art[6]->field3))
        ->setCellValue('D8', ''.utf8_encode($art[6]->field4))
        ->setCellValue('E8', ''.utf8_encode($art[6]->field5))
        ->setCellValue('F8', ''.utf8_encode($art[6]->field6));
```

I'm surely missing something, but I can't figure out what it is. Any suggestion?